# Jenkins Build Distribution among Slaves

Tags: jenkins

I need to get some advice about the way to control the way Jenkins Slaves are used / Jobs are being triggered.

Background / Constraints:

1. I have a sequence of 10 jobs that run one after each other using the ***"Trigger parameterized build on other projects"*** option [Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) Plugin.
2. Each Build of these jobs must run on the same node (I am doing it by using ***"Build on the same node"*** which is also configured in the parameterized build plugin and comes from the [NodeLabel](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) Plugin).
3. I have 5 Slaves (current number of executors per slave is 1 but i am open for suggestions here...)
4. Once Slave is occupied by a Build Sequence, no other job can run on it. When I had only 1 slave, the way I enforced it was using the ***"Block build when downstream project is building"***
5. The way I configured the slave to be chosen when the first Job is triggered is one of the following: (None of them solved my problem)

   a. Using the ***"Restrict where this project can be run"*** and put there a label that all relevant slaves will point to.

   b. Using the option of "This build is parameterized" ([Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) Plugin) and then add a ***"Node"*** parameter with the list of Slaves that the User can choose from.

**What I want to achieve?**

- When a User triger the build of the First Job in the Build Sequence, this Build will be done on once of the idle Slaves. (I mean a slave that is doing nothing at the moment)
- If there are no idle slaves, then it will join a queue of one of them (doesn't matter which)

Any suggestions how to solve it?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

Try passing ${NODE_NAME} as a NodeLabel as a post-build trigger to the downstream jobs. If that works, you may need to pass it every job.

Answer (score 0):

Try node-label parameter plugin. you can make Jobs to run slave node which is free at that movement